# What is the difference btw these two octave statements used for Regularized Logistic Regression in ML

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, octave, logistic-regression

I have came across 2 similar octave statements one of which doesn't provide the right result. The code is supposed to calculate cost function of Regularized Logistic regression.

```
J=(1/m)*sum(-y'*log(h)-(1-y')*log(1-h)) + (lambda/2*m)*sum(theta(2:end).^2;
%Bad one

J = (sum(-y' * log(h) - (1 - y')*log(1 - h)) / m) + lambda *sum(theta(2:end).^2)/ (2*m); 
%good one
```

please someone tell me the difference btw these two.

Comment: "Btw" is short for "by the way". You mean to say "between". There is no need for abbreviating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first one you have `lambda/2*m`. This is `(lambda/2)*m`. While in the second you have `lambda/(2*m)`. So in the first expression you a multiplying with `m`, and in the second dividing by `m`. Also note that first expression misses a bracket at the end.